# Executing wget in remote server with JSch

Tags: java, jsch

I'm trying to execute a sequence of command using the JSch library, everything trought SSH:

1. "cd /root/downloads/"
2. "wget mydownloadlink/file.rar"
3. "scp -f file.rar"

But this don't work, look a peace of my code:

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

            //Enter in directory to download
            String cdCommand ="cd /root/downloads/";
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(cdCommand);

            //Execute wget command
            String wgetCommand = "wget "+linkDownload;          
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(wgetCommand);

            // exec 'scp -f rfile' remotely
            String command = "scp -f " + rfile;
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

            // get I/O streams for remote scp
            OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();
```

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The `channel.connect()` is executing the last command you provided to it.  You need to create a new channel exec/connect for each command you want to run.  You should also open/retrieve the error stream because it probably showed an error in this case.